# Extending VC++ compiler for instrumentation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am very new to the windows world and development. I want to extend the VC++ compiler so that I can add some instrumentation instructions in a "pass" before creating the final shared lib. I googled somewhat, read some docs, installed Visual Studio and the compiler to play around but haven't been able to find a straightforward solution.  Any pointers will be really helpful

Thanks

Comment: The Visual C++ compiler is not extensible in any way that I'm aware of.

Comment: You can add pre-build and post-build steps to various parts of the project.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165412.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of instrumentation you’re looking for, and why do you need that.

But you might take a look at [/Gh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h.aspx) and [/GH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc11y76y.aspx) compiler switches, and implement custom `_penter` and `_pexit` functions in your shared library. Unfortunately, if you target AMD64 you’ll have to code these hook functions in assembly.

**Update:** here's an [open source](https://github.com/tyoma/micro-profiler) [visual studio plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArtemGevorkyan.MicroProfilerx64x86) that does exactly that, implements performance instrumentation using that mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

What you described seems close to Profile Guided Optimization in Visual Studio:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k32f4k.aspx. 
Not sure if it allows you to provide your own instrumentation database though, but, worth a look: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/438sd1tf.aspx